# Ubuntu won't recognize my hard drive

Tags: installation, windows, hard-drive

I am trying to install Ubuntu 10.10 and remove my existing Windows Installation.  Ubuntu loads fine from the optical drive but then can't find a hard drive to install itself to.  Both my optical / hard drive are SATA.  I read somewhere that if my bios settings have my SATA Controller running in IDE mode that I should switch them to AHCI.  I tried this and now the optical disk isn't recognized either (it just fails to boot from cd and jumps to windows after a spell).

I do so badly want to replace Windows, but I'm not off to a good start.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the hard drive to AHCI but leaving the optical drive as an IDE did the trick.  Installing now.